# iTerm is not using any config files when invoked for ssh

Tags: ssh, iterm

What I want to do: open an iTerm window/tab, and ssh to some remote system. On that remote system, I need the following exports to be "effective":

```
export LANG="C"
export LC_ALL="C"
```

When I open that iTerm tab/window manually, and type `ssh whatever.host` ... that works nicely (as I have these exports in my .bashrc on my Mac).

Now I configured Firefox to use iTerm for ssh-URIs, like `ssh://whatever.host`.

That works like I charm - I can click such URLs and a new iTerm tab/window shows up, and ssh was already called, and I am logged into that remote host. But: these exports are **not** visible.

I tried to use *.bashrc*, *.bash_login*, *.bash_profile* and also put the exports file into a *./ssh/rc* file.

But nothing seems to work ( I checked stuff such as [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/320065/bashrc-not-sourced-in-iterm-mac-os-x) or [ssh documentation](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm#ch08-74105.html)).

And just to be fully precise: actually, in my home directory, my *.bash_profile* file is a link to *.bashrc*. But even when I just put these exports into three *.bash login/profil/rc* files it doesn't help.
: the "manual" ssh sees the exports, but an iTerm triggered by Firefox does not.

In other words: how can I make sure that the ssh session that is "triggered" using an iTerm session sees these exports?

( and no, I can't simply change the .bashrc on the remote systems to contain the required exports )

Comment: What do you mean, "you can't get it to work when Firefox is triggering the iTerm session"?  I don't see how an external app triggering iTerm will affect your environment variables on a remote host.

Comment: It's still not clear.  1)  How is FF triggering iTerm?  2) *Where* are these environment variables set, on your local Mac or on a remote host? 3)  What ssh session is being established?

Comment: @Allan Lets try again, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: When you log into the remote host, issue the command `echo $0` and post the output.

Comment: @Allen: that gives `-bash`

Comment: See this relevant post:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108427/i-have-an-environment-variable-for-lang-set-in-profile-but-it-is-not-getting  I don't know how you have `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` linked, but `.bash_profile` should technically ***source*** `.bashrc`